# Devicetoken of iphone for push notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have tried PushMeBaby as server. The problem which I am facing is that the Push notification gets activated as when the app launches it prompts me to connect to itunes for push notification, but neither the

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

nor

```
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
```

get called. So I am not able to get the device token to push the notification to my device from PushMeBaby mac server for testing. I am having a jailbroken iphone 2g with iPhone OS 3.1.2

Can anyone help me with this...

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using Jailbroken iPhone. According to my experience APNS does not serve 'hacked' devices and the first symptom is that they do not send a reply. You can borrow a device to verify this.

Comment: I have read some of the forums which said their app ran on jail broken device also....

Comment: I have never seen push notifications on the jailbroken devices.
Check out the http://bit.ly/cjg7y for confirmation of my theory :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)dToken { 

    NSString *strToken = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"%@",dToken];

    NSLog(@"deviceToken is : %@",strToken);

    strToken = [strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    strToken = [strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    strToken = [strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"deviceToken is : %@",strToken);
}
```